Cypress - Matching a query with a wildcard or regex
Consider the below code to intercept an API call. It checks if query parameter cliendId = 36. I want to make this code only consider the query param clientId and NOT its value of 36. So, I tried to use "*" instead of '36' and it did not work. I could not find the answer in existing stack overflow questions. How do I make cypress only intercept based on the query param name and not its value ?
cy
  .intercept({
    pathname: '/api/program/v1/program'
    query: {
      clientId: '36'
    }
  })
  .as('createProgram');


You can use path instead of pathname, then include the query in the pathname string with a wildcard.
When fetching first client 36 then client 48, I wait on each one and verify it's clientId, using the same cy.intercept():
cy.intercept({ path: '/todos/1?clientId=*' }).as('client')

...

cy.wait('@client').its('request.query').should('have.property', 'clientId', '36')
cy.wait('@client').its('request.query').should('have.property', 'clientId', '48')


From RouteMatcher options



Option
Description




path
HTTP request path after the hostname, including query parameters


pathname
Like path, but without query parameters




More examples
Matching a query key at any position
it('path with wildcard - key in any query position', () => {

  cy.intercept({ path: '/todos/1?*clientId=*' }).as('client')

  cy.then(() => {
    const win = cy.state('window')
    const queryString = 'age=22&clientId=48&countryId=22'
    win.fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1?${queryString}`)
  })

  cy.wait('@client').its('request.query').should('have.property', 'clientId', '48')
})



Matching two keys out of three in strict order
it('path with regex - matches clientId followed by countryId (in strict order)', () => {
  
  cy.intercept({ path: /\/todos\/1\?(.*clientId=.*)(.*countryId=.*)/ }).as('client')

  cy.then(() => {
    const win = cy.state('window')
    const queryString = 'age=22&clientId=48&countryId=22'
    win.fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1?${queryString}`)
  })

  cy.wait('@client').its('request.query')
    .should(query => {
      expect(query).to.have.property('clientId', '48')
      expect(query).to.have.property('countryId', '22')
    })
})



Matching two keys out of three in any order
it('path with regex - matches clientId and countryId in any order', () => {
  
  cy.intercept({ path: /\/todos\/1\?(?=.*countryId=.*)(?=.*clientId=.*)/ }).as('client')

  // (?=.*key=.*) is positive lookahead that allows key to be in any order

  cy.then(() => {
    const win = cy.state('window')
    const queryString = 'age=22&clientId=48&countryId=22&gender=male'
    win.fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1?${queryString}`)
  })

  cy.wait('@client').its('request.query')
    .should(query => {
      expect(query).to.have.property('clientId', '48')
      expect(query).to.have.property('countryId', '22')
    })
})


I would encourage hands-on experimentation, as it's a great way to improve skills.

Will this work if more query params are introduced or if the order of query params gets changed ? E.g. We only care about intercepting cliendId. But in the future more params are added like age, country etc. which might come before the cliendId in the url.

I'll give you further examples.

You could use the RouteHandler function to assign the alias dynamically.
As an example, I fire the fetch from inside the test and stub the response (just for illustration).
cy.visit('https://example.com');

cy.intercept({
  pathname: '/over/there'
  },
  (req) => {

    // Assigning the alias if the query meets the condition
    if (req.query['name']) {
      req.alias = 'ferret'
      req.reply({trousers: 'up'}) // stubbing the response, since the URL isn't valid
    }
  }
)

// Firing the fetch with a query attached
cy.window().then(win => {
  win.fetch('https://example.com/over/there?name=ferret')
})

// Waiting for the alias
cy.wait('@ferret')
  .should(interception => {

    // confirming it matches request and response (for illustration only)
    expect(interception.request.query.name).to.eq('ferret')
    expect(interception.response.body.trousers).to.eq('up')
  })



cy.intercept({
  method: 'GET',
  url: /.*clientId=.*/,
}).as('apiCall');

Hope this is useful.
KR

Yes this works on my sample too.
